# ELF x86 executable entry point

Tags: elf, ptrace

```
void  *entrypoint;
/*virtual address of process*/
fscanf(debuggedfile, "%p", &entrypoint);
```

where debuggedfile is the stream to an elf file at the offset where int entry point is.
when i use ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, 0, entrypoint, 0) it returns -1

Answer (score 1):

ELF is a binary file format. `fscanf` is for reading from text files. Try `fread` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing code that parses ELF files, I would suggest
using a standard library like [libelf](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/elftoolchain/wiki/libelf) instead of coding your
own ELF parser by hand.

That way you would let libelf handle the corner cases that arise
occasionally, for example, ELF objects that use extended section numbering.

There are active open-source projects developing [BSD licensed](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/elftoolchain/wiki/libelf)
and [GPL'ed](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html) implementations of libelf---take your pick.

Comment: Thanks seems i'm not yet ready for doing this by myself (I always hate to use libraries cause i want to understand how everything works) I'll give it a try